# jQuery show message when one option is selected twice

Tags: jquery, html

I have form with one simple input text and another option select dropdown.So my markup is like this

```
 <div id="form-wrap" style="width:500px; margin: 0 auto;">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th width="55%">Service Name</th>
        <th width="35%">From Price</th>
        <th width="10%"></th>
      </tr>
          <tr id="template">
            <td id="example" width="55%">
              <select name="service-name" id="service-name" style="width:230px;">
                <option value="" selected>--select--</option>
                <option value="service-1">service-1</option>
                <option value="service-2">service-2</option>
                <option value="service-3">service-3</option>
                <option value="service-4">service-4</option>
              </select>
            </td>
            <td width="45%"><input type="text" name="from-price" id="from-price" /></td>
            <td width="10%"><input type="button" id="remove" value="remove row" /></td>
          </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="button" value="+ Add Row" id="add-row" />
  </div>
```

Under the form I have button called as Add row. So when someone clicks on it, it will add another row and also another button as remove which will remove the row with that selected button row. The jQuery code is like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    id = 0;
    var template = jQuery('#template');
    jQuery('#add-row').click(function() {
      var row = jQuery(template).clone();
      var templateSelectedIndex = template.find("select")[0].selectedIndex;
      template.find('input:text').val("");
      row.attr('id','row_'+(++id));
      row.find('#remove').show();
      row.find("select")[0].selectedIndex = templateSelectedIndex;
      template.after(row);
    });
    jQuery('#form-wrap').on('click','#remove',function() {
      jQuery(this).closest('tr').remove();
    });
```

});

Here it is working fine. Here is the working fiddle link

http://jsfiddle.net/NewUserFiddle/LT7gM/

But in this I want another extra option. You can see I have option like

```
 <select name="service-name" id="service-name" style="width:230px;">
  <option value="" selected>--select--</option>
  <option value="service-1">service-1</option>
  <option value="service-2">service-2</option>
  <option value="service-3">service-3</option>
  <option value="service-4">service-4</option>
</select>
```

So I want that when someone selects one option in a row `(lets say Service1)` and then adds another row and again chooses the same previous selected option `(here it is Service1 as Service1 has been selected in previous row)` then it should show an alert message that sorry the option name has been selected previously. So can someone tell me how to do this? Any help will be really appreciable. Thanks. Any help??

Comment: All newly added select dropdown have same 'id' .. why are you not using 'class' .. ? OR while adding a new row ... change the id like 'service-name1', 'service-name2', 'service-name3' .. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
jQuery('#add-row').click(function () {
    var row = jQuery(template).clone();
    var templateSelectedIndex = template.find("select")[0].selectedIndex;
    template.find('input:text').val("");
    row.attr('id', 'row_' + (++id));
    row.find('#remove').show();
    row.find("select")[0].selectedIndex = templateSelectedIndex;
    template.after(row);
    $("#template").find("select:first option:first").prop("selected","selected");
});
```

[**DEMO here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/LT7gM/7/)

Comment: thanks for the answer. It is the solution that I was really looking for. Well I have a question you have used 
`row.find("select")[0].selectedIndex = 0;`
can you tell me what is the meaning of here?

Comment: @NewUser In your code, when row is appended dynamically, if dropdown is changed say "service-1", newly added row also contains "service-1" as selected. I wrote `row.find("select")[0].selectedIndex = 0;` to prevent it.

Comment: can you check your fiddle? I have seen something wrong in the demo. Lets say you will select service-1 and enter text hello in the input text and again when you will click on add-row then you can see service-1 is not showing selected in the last row..it is only showing entered text?

Comment: `row.find("select")[0].selectedIndex = 0;` is simply not showing the selected option in the previous row but `row.find("select")[0].selectedIndex = templateSelectedIndex;` is showing the entered values in the row..

Answer (score 1):

As a concept...

```
if $( select#service_1 ) exists

    alert("already added")

else

    add new select box

end if
```

You seem to have a good grasp of jquery to implement the pseudo code.

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but it appears as if you want to ensure that a user can only select one of each option. In other words, you want to prevent a user selecting service-1 on more than one row.

To do this, you can attach an event listener to each select, cycle through all the select inputs, and ensure that no duplicates are found. This is the code I put together:

```
jQuery('#form-wrap').on('change', 'select',function(event) {
    var services = {};
    var valid = true;
    $('#form-wrap select').each(function(index, element) {
        if (services[element.selectedIndex])
            valid = false;

        if (element.selectedIndex != 0)
            services[element.selectedIndex] = true;
    });

    if (!valid)
    {
        alert('Sorry, that service has already been selected');
        this.selectedIndex = 0;
    }
});
```

and here is a [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/crDhz/)

Comment: can you check your fiddle? I have seen something wrong in the demo. Lets say you will select service-1 and enter text hello in the input text and again when you will click on add-row then you can see service-1 is not showing selected in the last row..it is only showing entered text?

Answer (score 0):

Possibly an if statement with a event listener.

*Something like; if Service 1, listen for Service1 as Service1, if so = Biggity bam!*

Below may get you in the right direction.

```
  if (Service1) init();
        else addEventListener(Event.yourstuffhere, init);
    }
```